# How to get singleton instance in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, singleton, .net-6.0

I`m creating a Web Api .Net 6  with mongodb and I have been following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

According to the tutorial, you start the instance in the Program.cs file like this :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<BookStoreDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("BookStoreDatabase"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<BooksService>();
```

And you get the instance in the controller like this :

```
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BooksService _booksService;

    public BooksController(BooksService booksService) =>
        _booksService = booksService;
}
```

How do I get the instance outside the controller ?

I also have a second class I wish to add as singleton, this class doesn't have arguments in it's constructor. Can I just add it using "Services.AddSingleton" or do I need to do something in "Services.Configure"? How would I get it's instance?

Comment: _"I also have a second class I wish to add as singleton, this class doesn't have arguments in it's constructor."_ - is this class registered in DI? Can you modify it, i.e. add parameters to it's constructor?

Comment: Yes, I can modify it's constructor. Should I add a private static variable in the class and save the instance in it? I saw this when reading about singletons but since this was not made in the example I thought there was another way.

Comment: _"Yes, I can modify it's constructor"_ - then add it. _"Should I add a private static variable in the class and save the instance in it?"_ - no you should not. "Standard" singleton pattern usually is not a best choice when you are using  DI. Just use DI from top to bottom and that's it.

Comment: *How do I get the instance outside the controller ?* - and inside what instead?

Comment: Why should I add an argument to the constructor of the second class when I don't need one. Also, I still don't understand how to get the instance of the second class even in the controller. Is it by adding a second constructor in the controller with the second class as argument or a second argument in the constructor that alredy exists of the controller?

Comment: Inside another class called by the controller,currently the controller is passing the singleton instance to this class as an argument in the constructor of this class.

Comment: @CarlosSiestrup, for your first question: Can you show an example of the class thats using the singleton, as well as how you declare it in the controller? Just trying to get more context on that

Comment: @CarlosSiestrup & @GuroStron: I can relate to this question. I have registered my configuration in `Program.cs` and it is available in my controller. However, I need to access configuration settings in almost all classes of my projects. Passing the configuration object as an argument whenever creating a new object of any type appears like a very strange approach. Using a classic Singleton approach you could do something like `Configurator.Instance.GetSetting("setting")` without any constructor injection. I do see benefits of DI, but especially when it comes to configuration settings, I don't.